# How do I pass a pointer to an Object to an FFI call in Squeak/Cuis?

Tags: smalltalk, ffi, squeak

I need to pass an array of Strings to an FFI call, I'd like to just do it as:

```
library passArray: {'hola' 'manola'} size: 2.
```

where `passArray:size:` is something like:

```
passArray: anArray size: anInteger
   <cdecl: void 'someFunction' (void* size_t)>
   ^ self externalCallFailed
```

But it fails with "Could not coerce arguments", no matter what I try.

Any ideas? (Yes, I could "externalize" all strings, and then build also an array of the pointers, but I don't think I need it.

Comment: Why you don't want to externalize all strings? If the reason is to avoid forcing the client from doing that, the only you need is an object that will do that for you (i.e., for the client). A general enough object will be able to handle this and any other need of marshaling a collection.

Comment: Not really, the user wouldn't really see the difference. Externalizing is using twice the memory needed, more copies, code to free the memory after it's been used or relaying on finalization, in generally more complexity, for something that should be simple, and only because I can't pass a direct pointer to the Array. Is this implementation dependent? well you may say so, or not, a different VM could just do what's needed to actually support passing a pointer to an Object...

Comment: If you pass a pointer to anObject, you should ensure then that anObject is not moved on GC... at leats while it is used "from the outside". May be I am stating something obvious, but I think that is the main reason for our externalizations

Comment: Yes! excellent point Carlos, thanks!!! I have tests specifically designed for that, checking whether the external function holds a references and/or makes a copy of the object.

Comment: OK, I understand. But be aware that exposing oops to external functions is a little bit risky. Even if you run in a single thread and the external function copies its arguments, it might call you back and your objects will likely move. I'm not saying you shouldn't do it, I'm only saying that cannot be adopted as a general rule, and that could add complexity too.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using a shared memory approach where data is to be shared between Smalltalk and C. The nice thing about shared memory is that you do not have to worry about moving the data between Smalltalk and C because the data is accessible from C and Smalltalk at the same time. Also because shared memory operates outside the VM and GC boundaries you do not have to worry about your data being garbage collected and ending up with memory leaks.

I do not know how to do this on Squeak because I am a Pharo user but must be something similar.

On C side

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define FILEPATH "mmapped.bin"
#define NUMINTS  (1000)
#define FILESIZE (NUMINTS * sizeof(int))

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    int fd;
    std::string* map;
    std::string map_contents;

    fd = open(FILEPATH, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
    perror("Error opening file for reading");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    map = (std::string*)mmap(0, FILESIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED) {
    close(fd);
    perror("Error mmapping the file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Read the file int-by-int from the mmap
     */
    map_contents = std::string(*map);
    std::cout<<"type of map is : "<< typeid(map).name()<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"I am reading from mmap : "<< map_contents <<" \n";

    if (munmap(map, FILESIZE) == -1) {
    perror("Error un-mmapping the file");
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

On Pharo side

```
examples
retrieveSharedValueStep1
<example>
"This method is an example that retrieves a struct from a shared memory section, in order for this example to work you need you first copy paste the contents of the Example Souce Code of the C++ file in the comment section  (you can also find the cpp file in the same directory where the git repo has been downloaded) of this class to a C++ source code file and compile it a run then replace the path of in this code of CPPBridge openFile: with the correct path of the bin that the C++ files has created , in order for this to work also you need to execute the C++ example first so it creates and file and share the memory.
After executing this method you can execute retrieveSharedValueStep2 to unmap and close the memory mapped file (keeps sharing the memory it just does not store it to the file)"

|instance fdNumber lseek mmapPointer data struct|

"Let's create an instance just an an example but we wont use it because we can use either class method or intance methods. You would want to use instance method if you want to open multiple memory mapped files meaning multiple areas of shared memory. Class methods for using just one"

instance := CPPBridge new.

"Warning !!! You must change the path to the file that is located in your hard drive. The file should be at the same location you built atlas-server.cpp which is responsible for creating the file. The number returned is a number that OS uses to identify the image , flag O_RDWR is just a number that states that we want to write and read the file"

fdNumber := CPPBridge openFile: '/Users/kilon/git/Pharo/CPPBridge/mmapped.bin' flags: (O_RDWR) . 

"lseek is used to stretch the file to a new size"
lseek := CPPBridge lSeek_fd: fdNumber range:3999  value:0.

"this is the most importan method, this method maps the file to memmory , which means it loads its contents into memory and associates the memory with the file. PROT_READ means we want to write the memory , PROT_WRITE to write the memory and MAP_SHARED is the most importan because it defines the memory area as shared so we can access it from other application"

mmapPointer := CPPBridge  mmap_adress: 0 fileSize:4000  flag1: (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE )flag2: MAP_SHARED  fd: fdNumber  offset: 0  .

"This assigns the pointer to our Pharo structure so we can use it to get the contents of the C structure located in the shared memory"
struct := CPPStruct pointTo: (mmapPointer getHandle ).

"data here serves as a convenience array its not necessary we use it just to collect information about the instance, the fd number of the file, the streched size of the file, the adress (point) where the file is mapped to in memory and struct that contains the values of the C struct that we received"
data :={ instance.  fdNumber . lseek. mmapPointer  .  struct}.
data inspect.

"Store data to the class so we can use it in the second method"
ExampleDATA := data.
^data 

"
Its also possible to write to the shared memory , in this case we use once again the C struct which has the following members (variables) : 
1) data = char[3000]  this is where we store the string
2) count = int this is where we store the size of the string
struct := {(mmapPointer getHandle  copyFrom: 1 to:3000 )asString . (mmapPointer getHandle integerAt: 3001 size:4 signed: false)}.
mmapPointer is the pointer that points to the first byte of the shared memory.
getHandle gives us the memory adress that the pointer points to
copyFrom:1 to:3000 copies byte from byte 0 (remember C counts from 0 , Pharo counts from 1) to byte 3000 because the string we store is stored as a char array of 3000 elements, each element is a char, each char is 1 byte in leght and represents a single character of the string. This gets the value of the first struct member.
on the other hand integerAt: 3001 size: 4 signed: false returns us the value count memeber of the C struct . its an integer in position 3001 because our string is a char[3000] and the size is 4 bytes because its an C int, signed false because we use no negative values because it does not make sense for a string to have negative length. This gets the value of the second struct member"
```

You can find more info by visiting my github repo because I have packaged all this into a library I call CPP (main intention was to use C++ but it works with C as well)

https://github.com/kilon/CPP

The **advantages** of my approach are:

1. you do not have to worry about GC
2. you do not need to copy data around
3. because shared memory using the memory mapped file system of the OS
       kernel you get a ton of speed plus your shared memory is always
       stored to a file automagically so you do not need to worry about
       losing your data in case of crash
4. the mmap file works in similar way to squeak image, storing live
   state
5. mmap because is an OS kernel function its supported in all OSes but
   also most programming languages , that means you can use this with
   any programming language you want

**Disadvantages**

1. Because this works inside a manual memory management region you lose
   the advantages of GC so you need to handle that memory yourself
   manually
2. Because its outside GC you also lose many of the dynamic capabilites
   of Smalltalk objects and thus you have to abide by C rules. Of
   course none stopping you from making a copy of the data as Smalltalk
   objects if you so wish or passing the data to existing Smalltalk
   objects
3. If you mess up you will crash Squeak VM easily as with any usual
   memory leak

Comment: VERY interesting approach! Thanks a lot for sharing, I will take a look at your code definitely. I believe I could use it on some other projects, where I do have the chance of changing the native library, but in this particular case I'm using a third party library, with lots of functions, so I'd had to wrap the exported functions to have them use shared memory, and then I'd have to maintain two sets of wrappers (Smalltalk and shared memory), I think it'll make it more complex. Thanks a lot for the suggestion!

Comment: Yes the library I mentioned is made to use C++ methods inside Pharo. This is NOT an ideal approach because generally using a FFI will be easier and more flexible. But in my case I cannot use UFFI because is extremely hard to turn the C++ code into a C DLL (Unreal is a huge game engine). My answer however was focusing only on your problem of sharing data between C and Smalltalk and NOT executing code. I think in that case this approach is much better than a simple FFI because it helps easily maintain the live state without worrying about the VM restrictions. This is something a FFI cannot do.